# Вывод элементов массива без перехода на новую строчку

Tags: python-3.x, массивы

Мой код

```
f = open('1.txt', 'r') 
lines = f.readlines()
str1= lines[0]
str2= lines[2]
print(str1,str2)
```

Его вывод

```
str number 1
 str number 3
```

В 1.txt есть такие строки

```
str number 1 
str number 2
str number 3
```

Что я хочу получить на выходе

> str number 1 str number 3

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дело в том, что в файле в конце каждой строчки есть перевод строки `\n`
для начала вам от этого надо избавиться, например так:

```
str1 = lines[0][:-1]
str2 = lines[2][:-1]
print(str1, str2)
```

т.е. отрезаем последний символ (который `\n`)

можно проделать это для всего файла:

```
lines = [line[:-1] for line in f.readlines()]
```